# Java Regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am developing a text highlighter in a file using the java regex pattern matching. Following is a code snapshot of it

```
SearchQuery=preprocessedModifiedArrayList.get(i)+[\\w\\s\\W]*?";
pattern = Pattern.compile(SearchQuery);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
```

in here "preprocessedModifiedArrayList.get(i)" contains the query to be searched in the text of the file. I have a problem that when the "preprocessedModifiedArrayList.get(i)" has "+" sign in it(example: if it is an equation) , it returns the dangling + exception.

I want to know how can I deal with this problem

Comment: I think you forgot one `"` - `...+"[\\w\\s\\W]*?";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may [quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) it:

```
SearchQuery=Pattern.quote(preprocessedModifiedArrayList.get(i))+"[\\w\\s\\W]*?";
```

Quoting will escape every special character in the pattern so that they behave as normal characters (like +).